# Tinymce 4, get current ID of element

Tags: jquery, tinymce-4

I am using Tinymce 4 as editor in my website, now I am using Jquery to set new content inside the editor for example:

```
<p id="1">text1 text1 text1</p>
<p id="2">text2 text2 text2</p>
```

When the user click on some paragraph I would like his ID number. I found a way to perform JS alert when the user click on the paragraph with the next code:

```
tinymce.init({
        selector: "textarea",
        'setup' : function(ed) { 
            ed.on('init', function(e) {
                $(ed.getBody()).on("click", "p", function() {alert('hello');});
            });
        },
```

How can I get the current ID of the paragraph (clicked)?

Answer (score 2):

If that code works, then the answer is:

```
var id = this.id;
```

...within the event handler, because `this` will be the `p` element, which has an `id` property. E.g.:

```
$(ed.getBody()).on("click", "p", function() { alert('Clicked: ' + this.id);});
```

---

Side note: Although `id` values starting with a digit are valid in HTML, they are not valid in CSS (and weren't valid in HTML4 and earlier), so for instance `#1` is an invalid selector in CSS (though some engines allow it). It may be best to steer away from `id` values starting with digits.

Comment: This should have been flagged as the answer. +1